# Expo ios Build error: You are not allowed to perfomr this Operation

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a developer role on the team.  App id is  setted, bundleidentifier is also matchesİ also my Certificates is also in the Apple developer Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. But when i try expo build:ios, after i choose let expo handle the process, on the Distribution Certificate part,  build is is failed. i get an error  and result screen is says:
" You are not allowed to perfom this operation. Please check with one of your team admins."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Developer role, you can not upload IPA into AppStore, by using developer role you can only test the app in your device. Either you need AppManager or Admin roles.